# Blocks with when and include_tasks

Tags: ansible

I have come across a bit of a strange behavior that i don't fully understand and i have so far not been able to find something useful in the documentation.

When you have a "block:" with a "when" condition, this condition on the block itself seems to make its way into included tasks, why?

Example:

```yaml
#playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - block:
      - name: Include stuff
        include_tasks: "set-x.yml"
      when: x is not defined
```

```yaml
#set-x.yml
- name: Set a fact
  set_fact:
    x: foo

- name: test
  debug:
    var: x
```

If you run above example the debug statement wont run at all and this is not what i expected.
My understanding was that the when condition on the block would only apply to if the block itself should be executed or not.
Cleary the condition gets carried over inside the include_tasks file and to my understanding this is not how include is supposed to work.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from [Conditionals with includes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-with-includes):

> When you use a conditional on an include_* statement, the condition is applied only to the include task itself and not to any other tasks within the included file(s).

This works as expected

```yaml
    - include_tasks: set-x.yml
      when: x is not defined
```

No task from the included file will be used

```yaml
TASK [include_tasks] ************************************************
included: /export/scratch/tmp8/set-x.yml for localhost
```

The situation is different with the *blocks*. Quoting from [Grouping tasks with blocks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#grouping-tasks-with-blocks):

> All tasks in a block inherit directives applied at the block level. ... The directive does not affect the block itself, it is only inherited by the tasks enclosed by a block. For example, a when statement is applied to the tasks within a block, not to the block itself.

If you put *include_tasks* into a block

```yaml
    - block:
        - include_tasks: set-x.yml
      when: x is not defined
```

the condition is applied to all tasks. Also to the included tasks, thus overriding the previous rule that a condition is applied only to the include task itself.

```yaml
TASK [include_tasks] *************************************************
included: /export/scratch/tmp8/set-x.yml for localhost

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************
skipping: [localhost]
```

Open an [issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues) if you think this is a bug.

Comment: Well... this is a bit of a strange behavior and it gets more strange because not only to the when: condition from the block make it to the include_tasks statement itself it ALSO makes it in to each statement inside the included file and further included files too.

i only found this out because i had a meta: reset_connection triggering a warning two levels down from the block about not supporting a when condition on meta:

Comment: Exactly, this is the point!